# Hi, I have some issue with the python pipreqs. It keeps telling me the usage instead of creating the right file

Tags: python, cmd, path

As you can see, I use the right command and it keeps telling me the usage instead of creating the right file for me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMG9M.png)

```
(WebScraping) G:\>pipreqs G:\PY CODE\WebScraping
Usage:
    pipreqs [options] [<path>]
```

And if I just randomly input the path file, it will tell me, file doesn`t exist.

```
(WebScraping) G:\>pipreqs s
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\anaconda\envs\WebScraping\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "D:\anaconda\envs\WebScraping\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "D:\anaconda\envs\WebScraping\Scripts\pipreqs.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
File "D:\anaconda\envs\WebScraping\lib\site-packages\pipreqs\pipreqs.py", line 488, in main
init(args)
File "D:\anaconda\envs\WebScraping\lib\site-packages\pipreqs\pipreqs.py", line 478, in init
generate_requirements_file(path, imports, symbol)
File "D:\anaconda\envs\WebScraping\lib\site-packages\pipreqs\pipreqs.py", line 157, in generate_requirements_file
with _open(path, "w") as out_file:
File "D:\anaconda\envs\WebScraping\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
return next(self.gen)
File "D:\anaconda\envs\WebScraping\lib\site-packages\pipreqs\pipreqs.py", line 81, in _open
file = open(filename, mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 's\\requirements.txt'
```

I finally solve this issue when I cd my host path in cmd to the document path without giving arguments in pipreqs order like this:

```
(WebScraping) G:\PY CODE\WebScraping>pipreqs --encoding=utf8
INFO: Successfully saved requirements file in G:\PY CODE\WebScraping\requirements.txt
```

But how can I use the normal orders like eveyone else:
G:\PY CODE\WebScraping
This keeps bothering me
I wonder is there someth

Answer (score 1):

Try adding quotes:
`pipreqs "G:\PY CODE\WebScraping"`

Comment: It works with
pipreqs "G:\PY CODE\WebScraping" --encoding=utf8